# Taylor Type series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion, closed-form

I'm stuck in the following series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\frac{d}{dx^n} \left( f(n-2x) \right) \left|_{x=0} \right.$$
where $f$ is a smooth function.
At first glance it resembles a Taylor Type series, but the argument of the function depends on the index $n$ of the sum, and so it's not a Taylor expansion around a fixed point as usual. 
I have no idea how to treat this sum. Any ideas, tricks or references?
Thanks!

Comment: what exactly is the question though? what do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x^n} f(n-2x) \bigg|_{x=0}=(-2)^nf^{(n)}(n)$$
So the result is not a series expansion as it does not depend on $x$, but a constant solely dependant on the function $f(x)$ used. Although the summation may not converge for example when $f(x)=n!/(-2)^n$, its value is given by
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^nf^{(n)}(n)}{n!}$$

Comment: Thanks Peter. The fact is that, the coeffients of the original series are really horrific; after long calculations I proved that the coeffients are exactly in the form above; my hope was that,  thanks to this false similarity to a Taylor series, I could say something on the sum.

Comment: @Papemax89 What was the original series? Perhaps you should post that in the question instead?